# How to get last element array (remove duplicate data) when I set condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have some data in the array will I filter to get the data I want.

In this array I want to take the most recent data in an array which uses certain conditions

I have an array

```
{

    "items": [
        {
            "idarchive": "1",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-10",
            "date2": "2016-07-10",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-10 17:32:55",
            "value": "10"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "2",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-11",
            "date2": "2016-07-11",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-10 17:32:56",
            "value": "30"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "3",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-11",
            "date2": "2016-07-11",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-10 18:11:32",
            "value": "50"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "4",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-12",
            "date2": "2016-07-12",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-11 10:02:44",
            "value": "15"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "5",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-12",
            "date2": "2016-07-12",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-11 11:12:05",
            "value": "20"
        },
    ]
}
```

In my array data, I have a date field 1 is the key for me to do filter.

Inside the array, I want to get the `last array` for the ``.
They assured the data will I get to be like this

```
{

    "items": [
        {
            "idarchive": "1",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-10",
            "date2": "2016-07-10",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-10 17:32:55",
            "value": "10"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "3",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-11",
            "date2": "2016-07-11",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-10 18:11:32",
            "value": "50"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "5",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-12",
            "date2": "2016-07-12",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-11 11:12:05",
            "value": "20"
        },
    ]
}
```

One data represent all data the same date.

I only can do a filter against the same data but have not reached a certain condition. This is my code

```
$output = array();
array_walk_recursive($myArrayDataAbove, function($item, $key) use (&$output){
    $output[$key] = isset($output[$key]) ?  $item + $output[$key] : $item;
});
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($output);
```

Thanks

Comment: please help us with  more words

Comment: Good luck with that, unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Show us that you have tried to do this for yourself. Show some code

Comment: I already make some code to eliminate array with same value, but not with condition...But fine if you get down vote for my question. I wil show my code for you

Comment: Hi @IsmailRBOUH Please check my update above.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please check my update, coz I only can do a filter against the same data but have not reached a certain condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your items are in a variable named $items.

Create a second variable where you are going to store the last results :

```
$lastItems = [];
```

Loop through your items to check the dates :

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // get the date
    $itemDate = $item['date1'];

    // if the date does not exist in your lastItems array, just create it :
    if (!isset($lastItems[$itemDate])) {
        $lastIems[$itemDate] = $item;
    } else {
        // the date exists, lets compare it to the item :
        $itemArchivedDate = new \DateTime($item['ts_archived']);
        $lastArchivedDate = new \DateTime($lastItems[$itemDate]['ts_archived']);

        // only if the current item archive date is greater than the stored one, replace it :
        if ($itemArchivedDate > lastArchivedDate) {
            $lastIems[$itemDate] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

There you go, your last elements are stored in the $lastItems variable.

Comment: Thanks @jiboulex for your help....I already test and nice works...Above, in my code I only can do a filter against the same data but have not reached a certain condition like your code